# SQL Server - What coding/development rules does your team have in place?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I asked a similar question last week and didn't get a very good response, so perhaps I didn't phrase the question in the right way.

I'd like to know what processes/policies/rules your team has in place for writing T-SQL code and database schema. Here are a couple examples:

```
1) All foreign key columns should be indexed
2) All primary key columns should be integer Identity
3) All stored procedures/user defined functions need comments
4) No underscores in T-SQL variable names
```

These are the sorts of things I'm curious about.

Thanks!

Comment: This is really community wiki stuff.

Comment: he who writes rules in stone, later wishes for a large bottle of whiteout! beyond formatting/style/naming/source code process just stick to guidelines and not absolute rules.  You might need to use a different PK (non identity some day) or an index on a FK is not needed, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Not really. We don't have indexes on some larger table FKs because we never delete or update the parent value, or poor selectivity
2. Mostly, but understand why. That said, I'd use the 3 digit code itself for a table that stored ISO currency codes such as CHF or GBP. And you'll still need a unique constraint on the natural key

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with all foreign keys being indexed.  If you have a foreign key to a master table of only 3 options, in a table with millions of rows, you have a massive overhead of pointless indexes.  A reverse lookup from the key to the data is unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like #1, #2 and #3 are all pretty poor rules.  It is not always necessary to index a foreign key. It doesn't make sense to create a surrogate key when a good natural key exists.  Comments don't compile so they get out of sync with code quite easily and can fool the reader.  They should only be used when absolutely necessary.  Commenting to fulfill a hard and fast rule is worse than a waste of time.

Item #4 is pretty good.  Teams I have worked on have been more concerned with things that go to the quality of the implementation (e.g. good error handling in all stored procedures, and Stored procedures do only one thing)

Comment: I have rarely run into a true natural key in 30 years of dealing with databases.  Surrogates are usually better than natural keys for performance reasons as well. If you have a true natural key a surrogate key for relating to child tables and a unique index on the natural key is generally the best performing option.